# Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gtk-vector-screenshot" - Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, software-center, gtk

Above message appears when starting any GTK app from terminal after (supposedly) uninstalling gtk-vector-screenshot 0.3.2.1-1ubuntu1 via Software Center. (didn't support as many apps as I'd hoped, or the apps I was most eager to use it with)

I've researched similar messages, but the solution seems to be either to upgrade the app to GTK3 or install it again with apt-get... well, that's fine, but I actually *want* it untinstalled, only *cleanly*. XD

I did find mention of a setting in GConf for a similar GTK daemon, but can't find anything similar on my system.

Any GURU out there have an idea what I need to do to clean up after this package? (should I also report the fault to the developer \ packager as a good citizen?)

TIA. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to restart your X11 session after installation to make it work and also when you want it completely removed after uninstall.

*Guru bonus gibberish:*

The program hooks a shim of itself into every X11 application by filling an environment variable that can only be set once at X11 start-up. The preloading happens in

> /etc/X11/Xsession.d/52load-gtk-vector-screenshot-gtk-module

Which reads:

```
# This file is sourced by Xsession(5), not executed.

if [ -z "$GTK_MODULES" ] ; then
    GTK_MODULES="gtk-vector-screenshot"
else
    GTK_MODULES="$GTK_MODULES:gtk-vector-screenshot"
fi

export GTK_MODULES
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm a little confused because, it's days, and many reboots between uninstalling and realising that this error appeared every time I launch a gtk app. I _thought_ that the X session ended when you shut down, and began anew after the splash screen... or possibly after graphical login. (I kinda lost interest in that after graphical logins came into being)

Are you saying I can just:-
`sudo rm /etc/X11/Xsession.d/53load-gtk-vector-screenshot-gtk-module` then `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop` then `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm start`

??

Comment: I did, in fact, resolve this by re-installing vector screenshot, rebooting, re-uninstalling it, and rebooting again.

It seems that this package breaks if you remove it before the reboot completes installation. :\

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue,

I just removed lightdm from access control list with command

```
sudo -i

xhost -SI:localuser:lightdm
```

and I dont know how but after that I didnt get any message like

> Gtk-Message: Failed to load module “gtk-vector-screenshot”